# R warning message [1 HIToolbox 0x00007ff80a4fc726 _ZN15MenuBarInstance22EnsureAutoShowObserverEv + 102]

Tags: r, rstudio

I kept getting these warning messages periodically when working in Rstudio or R.
Can you help me resolve this?
I have tried restarting r and rstudio. restarting the machine but no luck.
I have cut some of the errors to be post on SO.

```
> ggplot(diamonds, aes(depth)) + geom_freqpoly()
`stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
1   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff80a4fc726 _ZN15MenuBarInstance22EnsureAutoShowObserverEv + 102
2   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff80a4a0852 SetMenuBarObscured + 226
3   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff80a4a04ca _ZN13HIApplication15HandleActivatedEP14OpaqueEventRefhP15OpaqueWindowPtrh + 164
4   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff80a49a996 _ZN13HIApplication13EventObserverEjP14OpaqueEventRefPv + 252
5   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff80a462bd2 _NotifyEventLoopObservers + 153
6   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff80a49a3e6 AcquireEventFromQueue + 494
7   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff80a4893ec ReceiveNextEventCommon + 285
8   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff80a4892b3 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 70
9   AppKit                              0x00007ff803c90f33 _DPSNextEvent + 909
10  AppKit                              0x00007ff803c8fdb4 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1219
11  grDevices.so                        0x000000010da8db76 cocoa_process_events + 118
12  libR.dylib                          0x000000010d6ecf61 R_ProcessEvents + 33
13  rsession                            0x000000010cbff3f9 _ZN13rstudio_boost4asio6detail24descriptor_write_op_baseINS0_15const_buffers_1EE10do_performEPNS1_10reactor_opE + 693497
14  libR.dylib                          0x000000010d54e40d R_ToplevelExec + 637
15  rsession                            0x000000010cb915c1 _ZN13rstudio_boost4asio6detail24descriptor_write_op_baseINS0_15const_buffers_1EE10do_performEPNS1_10reactor_opE + 243393
16  rsession                            0x000000010c2eadfb _ZN13rstudio_boost4asio6detail30reactive_socket_accept_op_baseINS0_12basic_socketINS0_2ip3tcpEEES5_E10do_performEPNS1_10reactor_opE + 247835
17  rsession                            0x000000010c21b3aa rsession + 222122
18  rsession                            0x000000010cbd4b3a _ZN13rstudio_boost4asio6detail24descriptor_write_op_baseINS0_15const_buffers_1EE10do_performEPNS1_10reactor_opE + 519226
19  libR.dylib                          0x000000010d5eb9e4 Rf_ReplIteration + 100
20  libR.dylib                          0x000000010d5ed3b1 R_ReplConsole + 161
21  libR.dylib                          0x000000010d5ed302 run_Rmainloop + 82
22  libR.dylib                          0x000000010d5ed43e Rf_mainloop + 14
23  rsession                            0x000000010cbfead0 _ZN13rstudio_boost4asio6detail24descriptor_write_op_baseINS0_15const_buffers_1EE10do_performEPNS1_10reactor_opE + 691152
24  rsession                            0x000000010cbd1f54 _ZN13rstudio_boost4asio6detail24descriptor_write_op_baseINS0_15const_buffers_1EE10do_performEPNS1_10reactor_opE + 507988
25  rsession                            0x000000010c33d751 _ZN13rstudio_boost4asio6detail30reactive_socket_accept_op_baseINS0_12basic_socketINS0_2ip3tcpEEES5_E10do_performEPNS1_10reactor_opE + 586097
26  dyld                                0x00007ff800738310 start + 2432

12  grDevices.so                        0x000000010da8dbb7 cocoa_process_events + 183
13  libR.dylib                          0x000000010d6ecf61 R_ProcessEvents + 33
14  rsession                            0x000000010cbff3f9 _ZN13rstudio_boost4asio6detail24descriptor_write_op_baseINS0_15const_buffers_1EE10do_performEPNS1_10reactor_opE + 693497
15  libR.dylib                          0x000000010d54e40d R_ToplevelExec + 637
16  rsession                            0x000000010cb915c1 _ZN13rstudio_boost4asio6detail24descriptor_write_op_baseINS0_15const_buffers_1EE10do_performEPNS1_10reactor_opE + 243393
17  rsession                            0x000000010c2eadfb _ZN13rstudio_boost4asio6detail30reactive_socket_accept_op_baseINS0_12basic_socketINS0_2ip3tcpEEES5_E10do_performEPNS1_10reactor_opE + 247835
18  rsession                            0x000000010c21b3aa rsession + 222122
19  rsession                            0x000000010cbd4b3a _ZN13rstudio_boost4asio6detail24descriptor_write_op_baseINS0_15const_buffers_1EE10do_performEPNS1_10reactor_opE + 519226
20  libR.dylib                          0x000000010d5eb9e4 Rf_ReplIteration + 100
21  libR.dylib                          0x000000010d5ed3b1 R_ReplConsole + 161
22  libR.dylib                          0x000000010d5ed302 run_Rmainloop + 82
23  libR.dylib                          0x000000010d5ed43e Rf_mainloop + 14
24  rsession                            0x000000010cbfead0 _ZN13rstudio_boost4asio6detail24descriptor_write_op_baseINS0_15const_buffers_1EE10do_performEPNS1_10reactor_opE + 691152
25  rsession                            0x000000010cbd1f54 _ZN13rstudio_boost4asio6detail24descriptor_write_op_baseINS0_15const_buffers_1EE10do_performEPNS1_10reactor_opE + 507988
26  rsession                            0x000000010c33d751 _ZN13rstudio_boost4asio6detail30reactive_socket_accept_op_baseINS0_12basic_socketINS0_2ip3tcpEEES5_E10do_performEPNS1_10reactor_opE + 586097
27  dyld                                0x00007ff800738310 start + 2432
>
```

Comment: Wow, that looks wrong. Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling? Is there anything outside of "the norm" (according to installation docs) in your installation?

Comment: Are you using Ventura?

Comment: yes @user2554330 I'm using Ventura

Comment: That's a known Ventura bug.  See https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2023-February/014666.html .